# Sending Message using facebook Graph API

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, http-post

I'm trying to send a message to a facebook user, using POST method :

Here is the function :

```
router.post('/post/message/:userid', function (req, res, next) {
  messageData = {
    recipient: {id: req.params.userid},
    message: {text:req.body.text}
  }
  console.log( messageData );
  request({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+ pageid +'/messages',
    qs: {access_token: token_raw},
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
    } else if (response.body.error) {
      console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
    }
  });
});
```

But then here are the console logs :

```
{ recipient: { id: '**ClientID**' },
  message: { text: 'hello' } }
   type: 'OAuthException',
 Error:  { message: '(#100) No matching user found',
   code: 100,
   fbtrace_id: 'FlDy9Ypfen8' }
```

While "**ClientID**" is actually a valid userID.

Any idea ?